# Laravel : unique() not applied in migration

Tags: laravel, postgresql

In my migration, I have this column:

```
$table->foreignId('child_id')
      ->references('id')
      ->on('myschema.users')
      ->nullable()
      ->unique()
      ->constrained();
```

Why `unique()` is not applied?
I don't see it in the list of constaints in PgAdmin for this column.

Answer (score 1):

Because 'child_id' is foreign_key and always foreign_key is unique that's why **unique** is not applied also you don't need to mention unique while creating forign_key in migration. I hope this can be helpful to you.

Comment: It's untrue, my columns `parent_id` and `child_id` are foreign keys, one should be unique while the other should not. I finally fixed it by adding an extra line with `$table->unique('child_id');`

Comment: @DevonDahon- Please provide all information related to the question because you can't mentioned parent_id in the question